# Why is there no back to questions button?

Tags: discussion, design, navigation

This isn't a criticism by any means, nor do I wish to see one added.  I simply ask because I'd like to know the design motivation for it.  I personally like it, but whenever I try to implement similar navigation (no back button on the page); I'm constantly asked "Where's the back button?"

Comment: In my experience, it's fairly rare to see pages with a "back" button (unless they're displaying a list of results, in which case there is one on SO as well). This feature is already provided by the browser, and users are already comfortable using it there. They either won't use the one on your page at all, or it will confuse them when they try to use it in conjunction with the browser's back button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Your browser has one. There's no need to reimplement the functionality, especially since the browser's back button already works well.
2. The homepage can always be returned to by clicking on the logo.